# XmlSerializer ignoring attribute overrides when serializing

Tags: c#, xml

I have a complex graph and each and every property has a custom attribute. Once I have an object, I traverse the properties, check the custom attribute and if necessary, add the property to be ignored:

```
var ignoreAttribute = new XmlAttributes() {
    XmlIgnore = true
};
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

var objType = obj.GetType();
var properties = objType.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in properties)
{
    var attrib = property.GetCustomAttribute<ExportLevelAttribute>();
    if (!attrib.Values.Contains(level))
    {
        try
        {
            var element = property.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementAttribute>();
            var name = element?.ElementName == string.Empty ? property.Name : element.ElementName;

            overrides.Add(property.PropertyType, name, ignoreAttribute);
        }
        catch { }

        continue;
    }
}

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRootObject), overrides);
    xml.Serialize(writer, obj);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Properties are being added to the overrides. However, when serializing, those properties which are set to be ignored are still being serialized.

Am I missing something?

Comment: important: when you use `XmlAttributeOverrides`, a new serializer assembly is generated **every time** you `new XmlSerializer(...)`. So: you **must** store and reuse the `XmlSerializer` instance if you want to avoid haemorrhaging memory (runnable assemblies are not usually collectable)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` passed into `XmlAttributeOverrides.Add` works at the `object` level, not the `member` level:  [XmlAttributeOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.add?view=netframework-4.7.2).

So when you add an override, specify the object type you got earlier:

```
overrides.Add(objType, name, ignoreAttribute);
```